# Search an element in all pages in Selenium WebDriver (Pagination)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I need to search for particular text in a table on all the pages. Say i have got to search for text (e.g : "xxx") and this text is present at 5th row of table on 3rd page.
I have tried with some code :

```
List<WebElement> allrows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/table/tbody/tr"));
List<WebElement> allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='page-navigation']//a"));
    System.out.println("Total pages :" +allpages.size());
    for(int i=0; i<=(allpages.size()); i++)
        {
            for(int row=1; row<=allrows.size(); row++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows.size()); 
                    String name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/table/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[1]")).getText();
                    //System.out.println(name);
                    System.out.println("Row loop");
                    if(name.contains("xxxx"))
                        {
                            WebElement editbutton = table.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/table/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[3]"));
                            editbutton.click();
                            break;
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Element doesn't exist");
                    }
                    allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='page-navigation']//a"));
                }

            allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='page-navigation']//a"));
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            allpages.get(i).click();
        }
```

Sorry, i missed to describe the error.  Well this code gets executed properly, it checks for element "xxx" on each row of every page and clicks on editbutton when its found.

After that it moves to 
  "allpages.get(i).click();" // code is for click on pages

But its unable to find any pagination, so it displays error of "Element is not clickable at point (893, 731). Other element would receive the click...."

Comment: This is going to be really difficult for us to help you unless you post what error you are getting where, and what the HTML(s) looks like.

Comment: According to your update. Exception text must tell, _which_ element should recieve a click. Try to inspect if it doesn't 'cover' the needed element

Comment: Well here, after it clicks on editbutton...it moves to further code i.e. "allpages.get(i).click" and tries to search for pagination. So basically it doesn't end up with the code after the "xxx" elment is found

Answer (score 0):

For every page loop you use one table WebElement object. So I assume that after going to the next page you get StaleElementReferenceException. I guess the solution could be with defining table on every page loop. Move this line `List<WebElement> allrows = table.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='table']/table/tbody/tr"));` after `for(int i=0; i<=(allpages.size()); i++)` too

EDIT: And, btw, at this line `allpages.get(i).click()` I think you must click the next page link, not the current one as it seems to be